# Magento customer autologin

Tags: magento, authentication

I read the post regarding the magento autologin as admin : Magento auto login as admin. I tried to get it working with customers. But I can't get it done. The customer seems to be logged in but on redirecting to the index the user is not logged in.
It would be great if you could provide any advice...
Thank you!
Bernd

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/10209/autologin-on-frontend-from-the-backend

Answer (score 2):

If want auto log-in try below with out

```
try{
    $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer");
    $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getId());
    $customer->loadByEmail($email); //load customer by email i 
        /* if customer has ,then login */
        if($customer->getId()>0){
        $userSession = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session');
        $userSession->setCustomer($customer);
        Mage::dispatchEvent('customer_login', array('customer'=>$customer));
        echo "sucess";
        }else{
            echo 'fail';
        }
    }catch(Exception $e)
    {
    echo 'fail';
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! That script is nearly equal to mine. It echos success but after a redirect to the shop I get the login page again. I tested the redirect using `code`$url = Mage::app()->getStore($preferedStoreViewId)->getBaseUrl();<br/>$url = str_replace('autologin.php', 'index.php', $url);<br/>header('Location:  '.$url);<br/><br/>

Answer (score 0):

You can use this extension http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/login-as-customer.html
It is free and provide button in magento order admin edit page. I used this extension and its working as expected.

Comment: I also took a look at this extension. But it does not provide what I'm looking for: The best way would be to login a customer by providing http://myshop.de/autologin.php?email=anyone@somewhere.com&pass=whatever

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customerData);
        }
```

Comment: Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn() is true. But anyway. After the redirect to the index page the login appears again.

Comment: So you need to set a redirection page after the code executes. Like this $this->_redirect('checkout/cart'); paste the full code you are using. And check if this code Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setCustomerAsLoggedIn($customerData); running

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a little bit late, but you can have a look at this module : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/autologin.html.

It is not free, but you can login as customer from the backend easily, and setup the frontend landing page you want to be redirected when logged as a customer.

You can also download the customer list with autologin hashes (useful for newsletter third party tools)